# Trying to get data from data base in django

Tags: python, django

Trying to get data from database table,
i want to show data by when user click on the employee name and it should show data from **OverTime** table ,

but i am getting **Employee Id** in my **views.py** now i want to show data  from **OverTime** tabel in my template accordingly

i have attempted many way to get it dome but none of them worked, please mentor and guide me.

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default = '')
    emp_l_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default = '')
    emp_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250, default = '')
    emp_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name

class OverTime(models.Model):
    emp_user = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    overTime = models.FloatField( blank = True, null=True)
    reaion = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = True, null=True)
    date_ot = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.emp_user)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('add_Ot/', views.add_Ot, name = 'add_Ot'),
path('add_ex/<int:pk>', views.add_Ot, name = 'add_ex'),
```

**views.py**

```
def add_Ot(request, pk = None):
    emp = Employee.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    forms = OverTimeAdd(request.GET)

    detail_id = Employee.objects.filter(pk  = pk)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Over Time added !')

    contex = {
        'emp': emp,
        'forms': forms,
        'detail_id' : detail_id
         }

    return render(request, 'working/html/add_Ot.html', contex)
```

**html**

```
<tbody>
       {% for emp in emp %}
           <tr>
               <td class="detail"><a href="">{{ emp.id }}</a></td>
                  <td class="detail"><a href="{% url 'add_ex' emp.id %}">{{emp.emp_name}}</a></td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>

{% for data in detail_id %}
      <tr>
          <th class="f head-view">{{ data.overime.date_ot}}</th>
          <td class="head-view">{{data.overtime.overTime}}( in hours )</td>
          <td class="head-view">{{data.overtime.reaion}}</td>
       </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not clear what does not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Your question is not clear what you want, but as i can see you have to work on **views.py** and **django template** as well.
**views.py:**
From this
 `detail_id = Employee.objects.filter(pk  = pk)`

1. Change to
   `detail_id = Employee.objects.get(pk = pk)`
2. To get OverTime table data,write this:

```
datas = OverTime.objects.filter(emp_user=detail_id)
```

**html**

From this

```
{% for emp in emp %}
     do your logic....
{% endfor %}
```

Change to

```
{% for e in emp %}
     do your logic....
{% endfor %}
```

and for OverTime table data

```
{% for data in datas %}
      <tr>
          <th class="f head-view">{{ data.overTime }}</th>
          <td class="head-view">{{data.date_ot|time:"h:i a" }}</td>
          <td class="head-view">{{data.reaion }}</td>
       </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: You are not allow to iterate here, as you are getting only one object.

Comment: i have updated the question a little bit for better understanding.

Comment: @Vikas_kumar I have updated my answer, you may check now

Comment: thanks for kind support . well it worked.